# laravel install jenssegers/mongodb error ext-mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb

guy i try to install mongodb in laravel, so i import mongdo.dll already, but still error.

> Problem 1
> - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., 3.8.4] require mongodb/mongodb ^1.6 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.9.0].
> - mongodb/mongodb 1.9.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.10.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
> - Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb ^3.8 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., 3.8.4].

php extension install list.
php_mongo-1.6.9-5.6-ts-vc11-x64
php_mongodb-1.10.0-8.0-ts-vs16-x64

[image]

php.init file

```
    [PHP_MONGO]
extension=php_mongo.dll
[PHP_HTTP]
extension=php_http.dll
[PHP_MONGODB]
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

Comment: Can you please check the extension with the `phpinfo()` ? If it is showing in phpinfo then please check php-cli path and PHP server path is same.

Comment: I think php-cli disabled because in `phpinfo()` can't see cli. how to enabled php-cli in iis windows.

Comment: this is php version. I check with cmd.
`PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:23:59) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guy my answer edit file `composer.json`

Add this line

```
"provide" : {
    "ext-mongodb": "*"
},
```